# A genericity argument on family of disconnected holomorphic curves

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, moduli-spaces, pseudo-holomorphic-curves

Let $(W, \lambda)$ be an exact cobordism from $(M_+, \lambda_+)$ to $(M_-, \lambda_-)$ and $\overline{W}$ be the usual symplectic completion of $W$.  Let $\mathcal{M}(J)$ be the module space of all holomorphic curves in $\overline{W}$ with ends at Reeb orbits.  Here the ends of $u \in \mathcal{M}(J) $ are not ordered or asymptotically marked.

Let us make the following  fantastically  assumption:

> All pseudoholomorphic curves are Fredholm regular for generic  compatible almost
>   complex structures.

With above assmption, one can follow Wendl's Lectures on SFT ( arXiv:1612.01009 ) to define the homology $H_*^{SFT}(M_{\pm}, \xi_{\pm}, \mathbb{Q})$  and the cobordism map $\Psi: H_*^{SFT}(M_{+}, \xi_{+}, \mathbb{Q}) \to H_*^{SFT}(M_{-}, \xi_{-}, \mathbb{Q}) $ over coefficient ring $\mathbb{Q}$.

To  illustrate that $\Psi $ is independent on the almost complex structure, we need to consider the moduli space $\mathcal{M}(\gamma_+, \gamma_-, \{J_{s}\}_{s \in [0,1]})=\{(u,s) \vert s\in[0,1],  u \in \mathcal{M}_0^{J_s}(\gamma_+, \gamma_-)\}$, where $\{J_{s}\}_{s \in [0,1]}$ is   a generic homotopy so that the pair $(u,s) \in \mathcal{M}(\gamma_+, \gamma_-, \{J_{s}\}_{s \in [0,1]}) )$   parametric regularity,  and $\mathcal{M}_0^{J_s}(\gamma_+, \gamma_-)$ is index zero moduli space of  disconnected   $J_s$-holomorphic curves from $\gamma_+$ to $\gamma_-$.  The    symplectization levels $u_{\infty}$ may also contains lots of holomorphic curves with index larger than one.

Let $\{(u_k, s_k)\}_{k=1}^{\infty} \subset \mathcal{M}(\gamma_+, \gamma_-, \{J_{s}\}_{s \in [0,1]})  $ be a sequence of $J_{s_k}$ holomorphic curves, by Gromov compactness, $u_k$ converges to a  holomorphic building $u_{\infty}$ with total index zero. Here we assume that $J_{s_{\infty}}$ is not generic.  Since our curves $u_k$ are disconnected,  the main level of $u_{\infty}$ may include many index $-1$ curves  and others with arbitrarily large index. In addition, the    symplectization levels  of $u_{\infty}$ may contains lots of holomorphic curves with index larger than one.

> To avoid above  terrible situation，  Wendl claims that one can use a genericity argument to assume without loss
>   of generality that for any given $s\in [0,1]$,  at most one connected index $-1$ curve exists.   But I have no ideal how to do that, can someone explain more detail to me ?

Comment: I bet it is a Morse-theoretic statement where you perturb a Morse function so that its critical points have distinct critical values. Remark 7.4 of those lectures will help you. (Also, your "fantastic assumption" is ambiguous in language: typically, Fredholm regular means the cokernel of the operator is zero, hence there can be no negative index curves. Wendl's lectures also uses a notion of "parametric Fredholm regularity" and that might be what you wanted to say.)

Comment: Sorry for my inaccurate， the fantastic assumption is used to guarantee that the  homology $H_*^{SFT}$ and the cobordism map are well-defined.  And I should say that $\{J_s\}$ is a generic homotopy so that the pair $(u,s) \in \mathcal{M}(\gamma_+, \gamma_-, \{J_{s}\}_{s \in [0,1]}) )$   parametric regularity.

Comment: There is another point  mentioned by Wendl  that  there are only finitely many pairs $(s, u)$ where $u$ is a connected $J_s$-holomorphic curve with index  $−1$,  Hence, the  terrible situation  only occurs at  finitely may $s\in[0,1]$, it seems  that we can rule our the bad case after a sightly perturbation. But I don't know how to achieve that.

Comment: He is probably saying that you have a family {$(s,u)$} for which generically (with respect to $s$) the index -1 curves are disconnected, and nongenerically (i.e. at discrete values of $s$) there can be some $u$ which are connected. A toy model in Morse theory: Take the height function of a circle with two peaks of equal height and one higher peak. One critical level set contains two peaks (corresponding each to a nongeneric "connected curve") and two other points (corresponding each to "disconnected curves"). Now perturb the shape so each peak is at a different height.